# How to round DOWN to 2 decimal in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to round DOWN to 2 decimal places in C - EDIT: I actually need to change the value, not just display it to 2 decimals.
For example:

```
double x = 0.1234;
x = 0.12;
    
double y = 3.14159;
y = 3.14;
```

Is the an integrated function in <math.h> similar to floor(), or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Is your goal to round or to display 2 decimal?

Comment: @CGi03 Well now that you said that, routing down to 2 decimals is just displaying 2 decimals, so yes, just display 2 decimals.

Comment: `printf("%.2f", 1.23456789);`

Comment: @CGi03 Well I need to value to change so I used x = (double)((int)(x*100))/100;

Comment: There is a family of [`round`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round) functions also.  (But if you always want to "round down", then `floor` or `trunc` is what you want.)

Comment: Beware that the numbers `0.12` and `3.14` [do not exist in binary floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018). So even after rounding, it may be important to specify `%.2f` when printing.   Here's an example: `float f = 123.456; printf("%f\n", f); f = round(f * 100) / 100; printf("%f\n", f); printf("%.2f\n", f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well I need to value to change so I used x = (double)((int)(x*100))/100;

This works, but you are limited to a relatively low range, i.e: 123456789 * 100 overflows.

Check if `modf` helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dec2(double number)
{
    double fractpart, intpart;

    fractpart = modf(number, &intpart);
    return intpart + round(fractpart * 100) * 0.01;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", dec2(0.1234));
    printf("%f\n", dec2(3.14159));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.120000
3.140000
```

Comment: `round(fractpart * 100)` will not do the **round DOWN** as in the title for all `number`.  Perhaps the question title needs changing as this answer was accepted as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a `float` or `double` with 2 decimal places, specify a precision of 2 when using the `%f` format specifier.

```
printf("x=%.2f", x);
```